# Bootstrap Tooltip manual trigger not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing a serious dilemma here, i have used bootstrap tooltip on input tags for form validation i.e tooltip appears automatically around input tag when there is form validation errors, the problem is

1) The tooltip appears or triggers only when onBlur is called second time, although it should have appeared when cursor left the input tag the first time, code is

```
$("input#formName").each(function() {
     $("#formName").on("blur",this, function(){
        var x=document.getElementById("formName").value;
        //
        if (x==null || x=="")
        {
          var error = "Name Must Not Be Empty"; 
          $('#formName').tooltip({
            trigger: 'manual',
            title: error
            }).on({
                blur: function() {
                    $(this).tooltip('show');
                },
                focus: function() {
                    $(this).tooltip('hide');
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('#formName').data('tooltip',false);
        }

    });

        $("#formName").on("blur",this, function(){
            var y=document.getElementById("formName").value;
            if (y.length < 6){
                var error2 = "Length of Name Must Br Greater than 6";
                $('#formName').tooltip({
                trigger: 'manual',
                title: error2
                }).on({
                    blur: function() {
                        $(this).tooltip('show');
                    },
                    focus: function() {
                        $(this).tooltip('hide');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('#formName').data('tooltip',false);
            }
        })

});
```

2) I have two checks here,The above code works only once, not every time when the cursor leaves the specific input tag as in the code i.e if second condition is triggered, and after that i leave it empty, it should trigger the first function i.e "name Must not be empty", rather it goes with "Length must not be greater than 6"

Comment: `$("input#formName").each` suggests that you have identical ids in the markup, is that the case?

Comment: no i have another input tag but it is not identical they have different id's

Comment: Why does everyone say you have posted a duplicate question when nobody is answering your the question...

Comment: who is saying that you have posted a dup?????? also on  SO duplicate Question means that such kind of question has been asked previously, not that its the mirror image of someother question

Comment: this is for the 4th time now i have posted a question and there are no replies, when this happens i ask the question again and then there are answers... and yes i am going to ask again...

Comment: ah man dont get frustrated, first of all understand that its a community driven site so to answer a question is no ones obligation. you can ask question again but if its has a similar context then atleat close the previous one

Comment: Check my answer and do not duplicate your questions anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

I would change your override to one like this:

```
$("input#formName").each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.on("blur",this, function(){
        var x = $this.val();
        var error;

        if (x==null || x=="") { error = "Name Must Not Be Empty"; }
        elseif (x.length < 6) { error = "Length of Name Must Br Greater than 6"; }

        $this.tooltip({
            trigger: 'manual',
            title: error
            }).on({
                blur: function() {
                    $(this).tooltip('show');
                },
                focus: function() {
                    $(this).tooltip('hide');
                }
        });
    });
});
```

And change your all inputs to use class(`.formName`) instead of id(`#formName`)